# Is this PCM1860 connected ok for hardware control mode?

Tags: adc, i2s

I connected the PCM1860 ADC in this manner. I expect data on my oscilloscope on the digital output (pin 18). I have so far only seen square wave on the clock pins but nothing on the data pin. Is this connected ok?

[image]

Comment: Do you think the question is better suited for [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 0):

Pin 19 should have been left floating.